# How do I solve this "TemplateDoesNotExist" problem

Tags: django, view, django-templates

Keeping getting this error when i try running my Django application, The templates folder is inside the project folder so its on same level with app folder

I have tried importing os and added  os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates') to the TEMPLATE DIR but not working

Comment: if `SETTINGS_PATH` is literally pointing to the folder where your `settings.py` file is , then it is pointing to the wrong path (that would be `.../project/rootapp/templates` and not `.../project/templates`.

Answer (score 0):

you could start by specifying the path of the template directory in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['insert path to template directory'], 
        .....
```